# Does Doctrine 2.5 has an alternative to JPA @ElementCollection?

Tags: jpa, orm, doctrine-orm

Doctrine 2.5 has embedded objects feature, but what I am looking is a collection of these objects like Java Persistence API has. Basically, an annotation [@ElementCollection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) is what I am looking for doctrine.

Looks like Doctrine had such functionality developed in 2.2 version, but is it left over or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine 2.5 [does not support multiple embedded objects yet](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3579).

But you have following alternative solutions :

1. Serialising a collection of embedded objects into a single column
2. Map them as entity and one-to-many relationship but use OO to enforce the embedded object 's characteristic.For example , to well encapsulate them such that its lifecycle and behaviour can only be managed by its parent.

Reference:

- [Domain-Driven Design in PHP - Persisting a Collection of Value Objects](https://leanpub.com/ddd-in-php/read#leanpub-auto-persisting-a-collection-of-value-objects)
- [Persisting Value Objects in Doctrine](http://rosstuck.com/persisting-value-objects-in-doctrine/)